# Show xml nodes in textblock

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I want to display the content of an xml node in a Textblock. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<Hilfe>
<Hilfeartikel>
<Frage>Wie lange dauert es bis ein Ticket bearbeitet wird?</Frage>
<Antwort>Test</Antwort>
</Hilfeartikel>

<Hilfeartikel>
<Frage></Frage>
<Antwort></Antwort>
</Hilfeartikel>
</Hilfe>
```

And this was my try:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(@"Z:\hilfexml.xml"));
```

But i can not use the attributes. I try to google for it but didn't find anything. So i hope someone can help me. I always get a null reference exception. The null reference exeption only occurs when i try to do something with the values of the nodes. It allways stays in the root element.

Comment: I don't think there is some NullReferenceException anywhere in the code you posted. Please consider the exact line the exception was thrown at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
var doc=new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
var rootElement=doc.DocumentElement;

var Hilfeartikel=rootElement.GetElementsByTagName("Hilfeartikel")[0].InnerText;
foreach (XmlElement Element in Hilfeartikel.ChildNodes)
{
var frage=Element.GetElementsByTagName(Frage)[0].InnerText;
}
```

and so on.

Comment: tbxFrage1.Text = rootElement.GetElementsByTagName("Frage")[0].InnerText;
            tbxAntwort1.Text = rootElement.GetElementsByTagName("Antwort")[0].InnerText; Here this is that i changed and now it works thx for it.